# Printing items in list on new lines with compact code

Tags: python

I got the results I wanted by doing this:

```
list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
def new(x):
  for i in x:
    print i
```

and then calling `new(list)`
Results would be:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

What I would like to do is something like `print [x for x in list]`
but I can't seem to find the right answer searchin.
Is there a more compact way to plint out each item in the list on new lines?

Answer (score 1):

On *Python 3.x*, simply add a `sep` while you `print`:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(*lst, sep="\n")

# 1
# 2
# 3
# 4
# 5
```

**EDIT**: On  *Python 2.6+*, you need to import `print_function`:

```
from __future__ import print_function 
lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(*lst, sep='\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is :

```
new = lambda x:"\n".join(map(str,x))
print new(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an answer without `lambda` and `map()`:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print('\n'.join([str(a) for a in ls]))
```

Also, please do not call a variable `list` as this interferes with the `class` [list](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-list)